# Does malware use Oracle RDBMS Kernel Executable (oracle.exe) to steal data?

Tags: malware, windows, windows-10, virus-removal

I'm worried that my computer may have been infected by a virus. My Windows Virus Scan says that nothing came up, and a Chrome malware scan also turned up nothing. However, a process called Oracle RDBMS Kernel Executable is running on my computer now and is using a lot of memory (400 MB).

This process is able to access LAN ports and communicate information to databases. I'm worried that my computer has been infected and that my information is being sent to the malware author's databases.

Additionally, a process called Antimalware Service Executable is running as well and is using about 150 MB memory. This process is used by Windows Defender to fight malware. I'm worried that this program is running because it detected a virus in my system and is trying to get rid of it.

Comment: The Antimalware Service Executable is running to provide real time protection. That is completely normal. As for the RDBMS, have you installed any Oracle products?

Comment: And Chrome browser eating 1GB of memory don"t bother you? Oracle.exe can use a lot of memory by definition. For example https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/1022510/oracle-exe-consumed-80-physical-memory-on-windows-os Its not a sign of infection at all.